# jquery focus() doesn't work in slider

Tags: jquery

Why this code doesn't work? I tryed put alert(); it also nothing is happening.

```
    <script>
        $('#prev_next').focus(function(){
        $(this).next('input').focus();
        })
   </script>
```

piece jquery code:

```
options: {
        enabled: false,
        arrowMarkup: '<button id="prev_next" title="%title%" type="button" class="mfp-arrow mfp-arrow-%dir%"></button>',
        preload: [0,2],
        navigateByImgClick: true,
        arrows: true,

        tPrev: 'Previous (Left arrow key)',
        tNext: 'Next (Right arrow key)',
        tCounter: '%curr% of %total%'
    },
```

[image]

Comment: try event delegation

Answer (score 0):

This works if you don't have any element between the button and the input.

Instead next(), you can try this:

```
$(':input:eq(' + ($(':input').index(this) + 1) + ')').focus();
```